# Are my disc brake pads contaminated?

Tags: disc-brake, hydraulic-disc-brake

My rear brake never locks the rear wheel even with full pull on the lever, especially going down hill or fast. I can even pedal a bit with the brake depressed.

This is a recent issue and sometime in a ride the full braking force returns for a couple of minutes.

My pads are in a very bad condition and I've have new ones on order. My question is if they can be the reason for my problem? The bike was bought used so I don't know its history.

Rear pads:
[image]

Front pads:
[image: front]

Front, no flash:
[image: front pads]

And the disc, which looks ok:
[image: rotor]

Comment: They looked more glazed than contaminated. Give them a sand with fine sand paper to remove the shiny bits to see if it makes any difference. Bed the new pads in as per the instructions.

Comment: I cleaned them with alcohol as i found no sand paper lying around. Now they do have the shiny metal bits and i think this is how it should look (even though you said to remove just that) - but no change whatsoever to stopping power unfortunately...

Comment: Shiny metal bits yes, but the glassy black stuff needs to be made dull.

Comment: That was taken off indeed. I couldn't heat them on open fire or in an oven right? because they're resin based.

Comment: If you fell the lever tight, and if it has the same feeling as the front one, air bobbles should not be the problem. Those pads look in fairly bad condition, I would replace them anyway and I am pretty sure you will have a much better feel on the brakes. And if with new pads you have the same problem, at least you're sure the problem is not from there :) (P.S.: Make sure to clean the disc with a degreaser or with alcohol before installing the new ones.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These look pretty far gone, as suggested. Lucky the rotor isn't scored, or that would cost more than a set of pads.

Comment: Can it be the reason for the poor stopping action?

Comment: @PIXP: of course.

Comment: Replaced. Works great now as expected

Comment: @pixp Good work - thank you for posting an update.